# How to prepare Adapter For Showing ImageView Instead TextView upon need

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, adapter

i have a ListView for my Chat app, some Times i need to remove the TextView and Load an Image Depending on Data Input, for Achieving that i have some idea's and i have already tried one, but listview Messes Up when i add Images , any way, thought may be Could use Some Experience From Some nice people please about What is the right Way to do so? they ways that i thought are these:

1.Create 2 ViewHolders and ConvertViews set's, and load 1 set each time

2.have imageView in the listView as Invisible , and visible it on need (This one i tried but failed like said)

please if you could give me a tip or help i really appreciate, thanks Alot

a Part of What i have already tried:

```
     @Override
 public int getCount() {
return mCursor.getCount();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return mCursor.getString(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return mCursor.getPosition();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder holder = null;
if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_discuss, null);
    this.convertview=convertView;



System.out.println("ConverView null");

holder.PimageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.PimageView);
//PimageView is the One i have Problem With, it gets Visible When Inputs are Images
holder.wrapper = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wrapper);
//wrapper is my LinearLayout child of FrameLayout
holder.theMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.comment);
holder.theName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGname);
holder.theImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.MSGimage);
holder.lp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) holder.theName.getLayoutParams();
holder.paramsleft = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.LEFT);
holder.paramsright = new   FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,Gravity.RIGHT);

convertView.setTag(holder);

}else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

mCursor.moveToPosition(position);   
String imagenamer= 
(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("username")).split("\\@"))[0];
int isright= Integer.valueOf(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("isright")));



if(!"".equals(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("isfile")))){
 System.out.println("its a file");
String type=(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("isfile")).split("\\@ADAT")
[0]);
System.out.println("Type:"+type);
switch (type) {
case "image":
        //theMessage is replaced with PimageView and so TheView
        holder.theMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.PimageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
        System.out.println("its an image");
        holder.PimageView.setLayoutParams(new   
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(PViewWidth,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
if(isright==0){
holder.PimageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

}else{
holder.PimageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);

 }
```

but ListView messes up positions upon scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.  One is going the visible/invisible route.  If you go this route, you'll have to make the proper view visible and invisible on every call to getView(), and your getView will need to know which one to go with.

Option two is a totally custom Adapter based off of Adapter.  Specifically you'll need to overload getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType() in addition to the normal functions.  I'd probably go with route 1 for such a simple view, this option is better for complex views.

Comment: well i extacly did first one, take a look please i add the code

Comment: You really need to format that code.  But I don't see you setting the correct visibilities in the case of it being text.  You need to set them on both.  Other than that, tell me what problems you're seeing.

Comment: imageView is already "gone" in the xml, thats why, and this is just a part of it, since i have like 8 conditions like this , problem is for example if i should have 2 images on my list, i have 4, and whenever i scroll up and down it gets even more messed up resulting all textview's are removed and imageViews taken their places

Comment: Doesn't matter if its gone in the xml.  WHen you scroll, views are recycled.  You must set EVERY setting of EVERY field on each call to get view-  that means all texts, all images, and all visibilities.

Comment: that was not extact reason or solution, but it helped to help me fix recyclying a little more, so i accept the answer ty